Service Unavailable with Microsoft Graph (client credentials authentication from C# code)
I would like to retrieve some email attachments from my personal mailbox.
Everything works fine if I use the token I can copy from Graph Explorer even though it seems to expire and need to retrieve the "refreshed" one several times.
var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider(access_token); // access_token from Microsoft Graph Explorer.

var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(tokenProvider);

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

var user = graphServiceClient.Users[userId];

var messages = await user.Messages.GetAsync(); // Works fine.

Nevertheless, I get a Service Unavailable exception when I generate the token from C# code.
Too many retries performed. More than 3 retries encountered while sending the request. (HTTP request failed with status code: ServiceUnavailable).
var tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var requestBody = $"client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenEndpoint)
{
    Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
};

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseContent);

var access_token = $"{data["access_token"]}";

var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider(access_token);

var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(tokenProvider);

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

var user = graphServiceClient.Users[userId];

var messages = await user.Messages.GetAsync(); // Service Unavailable.

I also get an apparently valid token with 200 status code with Postman. I also tried to change the tenatId, clientId, etc. but it leads to other issues.
Does anyone have some insights what causes the issue?

Note that, token generated with client credentials flow won't work with personal accounts. You need to switch to delegated flows like interactive flow or authotization code flow to generate token that requires user to login atleast once.

Graph Explorer generates access token with permissions of signed-in(delegated) user. So, it works with Graph Explorer token.

As mentioned in this MS Doc, you need to use Delegated permissions that works with delegated flow like interactive flow or authorization code flow etc.. for retrieving messages from personal accounts.
Initially, I registered one multi-tenant Entra ID application by adding redirect URI in "Mobile and desktop applications" platform like this:

Now, I added Mail.Read permission of Delegated type in above app registration:

To authenticate with interactive flow, make sure to enable public client option:

In my case, I used below sample code that uses interactive flow to authenticate and got response successfully by signing in with personal account:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "common";
var clientId = "appId";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "attachments" };
    });

    foreach (var message in messages.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {message.Subject}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Message ID: {message.Id}");
        if (message.Attachments.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attachments:");
            foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  Attachment Id: {attachment.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"  Attachment Name: {attachment.Name}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No attachments found.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
    }
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}

Response:

Reference:
Access personal mail box using graph api - Microsoft Q&A by Carl Zhao - MSFT
UPDATE:
If still the error persists, try changing the scope value by passing only specific permission like this:
var scopes = new[] { "Mail.Read" };


Thanks for your explanations which help me a lot. I was trying to figure out how to implement interactive and authorization code flows (still needs to learn lots of things regarding authentication and authorization). With your configurations and code, when I'm redirected to the login popup, I can pick my company account which I don't want to use and if I use my personal one (@outlook.com) I get the error You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead.

Did you change tenantId to common and check whether the app you are using is multi-tenant or not?

Yes, I changed the tenantId to common with Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox). I also tried with a new App Registration with Personal Microsoft accounts only and have the same issue.

Could you include that error message by editing your question?

Sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you're asking for. Know I only have the following error You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead which appears in the web browser login prompt.

I want you to include that error snip and your app config images by editing your question

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
